# MongoDB: Aggregate $lookup b/w 'Customer' and 'Product' collections returns blank array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate

I have written a small query to get data from two collections,
here is my query as you can see:

```js
Customer.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Product",
      localField: "product",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "productdata"
    }
  }
]).exec(function (err, res) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error', err)
  }
  else {
    console.log(res);
  }
});
```

I am always getting below output:

```js
{
  _id: 605412b063db104dfcb3d78a,
  updated_at: 2021-03-19T02:55:44.098Z,
  name: 'bhavesh',
  product: '6052c356a76d435cf857aa3c',
  city: 'surat',
  __v: 0,
  productdata: []
},
```

My collections are as follow:

```js
// Customer collection
{
  "_id": ObjectId("6052c3e50016c24b24a37f4d"),
  "updated_at": ISODate("2021-03-18T08:37:17.659+05:30"),
  "name": "bhavesh",
  "product": "6052c356a76d435cf857aa3c",
  "city": "surat"
},
{
  "_id": ObjectId("6052c40202dce351e8448441"),
  "updated_at": ISODate("2021-03-18T08:37:46.184+05:30"),
  "name": "alex",
  "product": "6052c369b9395c55042373e6",
  "city": "ahmdabad"
},
{
  "_id": ObjectId("6052c4157d1616563c707732"),
  "updated_at": ISODate("2021-03-18T08:38:05.935+05:30"),
  "name": "lexa",
  "product": "6052c37321b64b4c40ac65a5",
  "city": "mumbai"
},
{
  "_id": ObjectId("6052c42efa94db04ccf19560"),
  "updated_at": ISODate("2021-03-18T08:38:30.411+05:30"),
  "name": "bhumi",
  "product": "6052c37ef633e64cb8b65423",
  "city": "surat"
}

// Product collection
{
  "_id": ObjectId("6052c356a76d435cf857aa3c"),
  "updated_at": ISODate("2021-03-18T08:34:54.187+05:30"),
  "name": "laptop",
  "company": "6052c217a1abc325b01ec87c",
  "price": 66
},
{
  "_id": ObjectId("6052c369b9395c55042373e6"),
  "updated_at": ISODate("2021-03-18T08:35:13.939+05:30"),
  "name": "charger",
  "company": "6052c2311993dc433c0657d7",
  "price": 50
},
{
  "_id": ObjectId("6052c37321b64b4c40ac65a5"),
  "updated_at": ISODate("2021-03-18T08:35:23.503+05:30"),
  "name": "tablet",
  "company": "6052c2311993dc433c0657d7",
  "price": 50
},
{
  "_id": ObjectId("6052c37ef633e64cb8b65423"),
  "updated_at": ISODate("2021-03-18T08:35:34.979+05:30"),
  "name": "bettery",
  "company": "6052c217a1abc325b01ec87c",
  "price": 500
}

// company collection
{
  "_id": ObjectId("6052c217a1abc325b01ec87c"),
  "updated_at": ISODate("2021-03-18T08:29:35.387+05:30"),
  "name": "artoon",
  "status": "active"
},
{
  "_id": ObjectId("6052c2311993dc433c0657d7"),
  "updated_at": ISODate("2021-03-18T08:30:01.508+05:30"),
  "name": "identix",
  "status": "active"
}
```

So basically I want data from 3 collections which have unique relation if you need more description please comment.

Answer (score 0):

The $lookup doesn't match anything is because the localField 'product' of Customer collection is type String and the foreignField _id of Product collection is type ObjectId.  The 2 values are not the same even though the look the same from your post.  Notice that the _id value doesn't have the single quote around it while other fields (product and company) do.

You need to make them all the same type in order for the search to match.  That is making

1. product field in Customer collection ObjectId type
2. company field in Product collection ObjectId type

Comment: on insert time i used product: ObjectId('6052c356a76d435cf857aa3c')

Comment: For some reason, it was not inserted as ObjectId but as String since the value is inside double quotes ( "product": "6052c356a76d435cf857aa3c" ) while the filed _id actually is ObjectId (  "_id": ObjectId("6052c4157d1616563c707732"))

Answer (score 0):

Try this query for performing join between 3 collections:

```js
db.Customer.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "Product",
            let: {
                product_id: { $toObjectId: "$product" }
            },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$product_id"] }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: "company",
                        let: {
                            company_id: { $toObjectId: "$company" },
                        },
                        pipeline: [
                            {
                                $match: {
                                    $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$company_id"] }
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        as: "company"
                    }
                },
                { $unwind: "$company" }
            ],
            as: "Product"
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$Product" }
]);
```

Output:

```js
/* 1 createdAt:3/18/2021, 8:37:17 AM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6052c3e50016c24b24a37f4d"),
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2021-03-18T08:37:17.659+05:30"),
    "name" : "bhavesh",
    "product" : "6052c356a76d435cf857aa3c",
    "city" : "surat",
    "Product" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("6052c356a76d435cf857aa3c"),
        "updated_at" : ISODate("2021-03-18T08:34:54.187+05:30"),
        "name" : "laptop",
        "company" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("6052c217a1abc325b01ec87c"),
            "updated_at" : ISODate("2021-03-18T08:29:35.387+05:30"),
            "name" : "artoon",
            "status" : "active"
        },
        "price" : 66
    }
},

/* 2 createdAt:3/18/2021, 8:37:46 AM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6052c40202dce351e8448441"),
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2021-03-18T08:37:46.184+05:30"),
    "name" : "alex",
    "product" : "6052c369b9395c55042373e6",
    "city" : "ahmdabad",
    "Product" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("6052c369b9395c55042373e6"),
        "updated_at" : ISODate("2021-03-18T08:35:13.939+05:30"),
        "name" : "charger",
        "company" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("6052c2311993dc433c0657d7"),
            "updated_at" : ISODate("2021-03-18T08:30:01.508+05:30"),
            "name" : "identix",
            "status" : "active"
        },
        "price" : 50
    }
},

/* 3 createdAt:3/18/2021, 8:38:05 AM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6052c4157d1616563c707732"),
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2021-03-18T08:38:05.935+05:30"),
    "name" : "lexa",
    "product" : "6052c37321b64b4c40ac65a5",
    "city" : "mumbai",
    "Product" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("6052c37321b64b4c40ac65a5"),
        "updated_at" : ISODate("2021-03-18T08:35:23.503+05:30"),
        "name" : "tablet",
        "company" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("6052c2311993dc433c0657d7"),
            "updated_at" : ISODate("2021-03-18T08:30:01.508+05:30"),
            "name" : "identix",
            "status" : "active"
        },
        "price" : 50
    }
},

/* 4 createdAt:3/18/2021, 8:38:30 AM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6052c42efa94db04ccf19560"),
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2021-03-18T08:38:30.411+05:30"),
    "name" : "bhumi",
    "product" : "6052c37ef633e64cb8b65423",
    "city" : "surat",
    "Product" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("6052c37ef633e64cb8b65423"),
        "updated_at" : ISODate("2021-03-18T08:35:34.979+05:30"),
        "name" : "bettery",
        "company" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("6052c217a1abc325b01ec87c"),
            "updated_at" : ISODate("2021-03-18T08:29:35.387+05:30"),
            "name" : "artoon",
            "status" : "active"
        },
        "price" : 500
    }
}
```

Comment: not working for me,
did you get the correct output? i am getting blank array

Comment: Yes i am getting the output. Check the collection name and field names.

Comment: I use same code here is repo https://github.com/kumbhanialex111/mongo_t_node/blob/master/controllers/filterControlller.js

Comment: You need to change collection name in query from `Product` to `products` (or whatever is correct) same in the case of `company` (to whatever is in your database)

Comment: name is same, you can see in models